# WebKitErrorDomain error 101 (in mapview)

Tags: iphone

here is my code i get this error

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?lat=%@&long=%@",
                 [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"map" ofType:@"html"],
                 @"17.734503", 
                 @"83.2999716"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
DirctionWeb.delegate = self;
[DirctionWeb loadRequest:request];
```

so here i connect webpage into google map html page why this error message please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the url isproperly encoded and has the +- on the lat and long, like so:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/?q=+17.734503,+83.2999716"]];
DirctionWeb.delegate = self;
[DirctionWeb loadRequest:request];
```

---

So, replace this:

```
NSString *htmlFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?lat=%@&long=%@",
                 [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"map" ofType:@"html"],
                 @"17.734503", 
                 @"-83.2999716"];
```

With:

```
NSString *htmlFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?lat=+.000000f&long=%+.000000f",
                 [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"map" ofType:@"html"],
                 @"17.734503", 
                 @"-83.2999716"];
```

Comment: thanks for u r answer...here i want pass latitude and longitude to map.html here is my code it's not working plz guide me                 NSString *htmlFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?lat=%@&long=%@", 
                           [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"map" 
                                                           ofType:@"html"], 
                          @"35.115403", 
                           @"-89.9045614724"];

Comment: thanks again i try u r code i print NSLog(@"url is %@",htmlFile); i get iClean.app/map.html?lat=+0&long=+0 like this